# iOS: is there a way of pressing a button such that it also presses another button?

Tags: ios, button, ibaction

I have a "Submit" button and a button that toggles between "Edit" and "Cancel." How do I get the "Cancel" button to return to saying "Edit" when I press the "Submit" button? If I press "Cancel," that button **will** switch back to "Edit."

This is what I have, and it doesn't work.

```
- (IBAction)submitClicked:(id)sender {
    [submitButton resignFirstResponder];
    if (inEditMode)
        [editButton setClicked:YES];
    ...
}

- (IBAction)editClicked:(id)sender {
    if (inEditMode) 
    {
        inEditMode = NO;        
        ...
        [sender setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else 
    {
        inEditMode = YES;        
        [sender setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    [editButton resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Thanks, John

Comment: Why send the sender a message when you can make it an ivar and access it directly?  Then you could make your setTitle calls with a little more safety.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is call the selector `- (IBAction) editClicked:(id) sender` to 
**simulate an edit button click** when the submit button is clicked. Your code for submit clicked should look like this:

```
    - (IBAction)submitClicked:(id)sender {
        [submitButton resignFirstResponder];
        if (inEditMode)
            [self editClicked:editButton];
            ...
    }
```

Note that you have to pass in the edit button somehow, so be a little careful, because the method `editClicked` uses both `sender` and `editButton`. You might want to consider consistently using the same variable, as @CodaFi said in a comment.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I was sick with influenza. I made your change, and the code does everything I want **except** changing the Title back on the editButton. Thanks.